# Python string clean up: string of an address in python using findall

Tags: python, string-concatenation, findall, string-conversion

I have this string:

```
"19369 Stevens Creek BlvdSte 130Cupertino, CA 95014"
```

that I would like to clean to two different strings:

```
["19369", "Stevens", "Creek", "Blvd", "Ste 130,", "Cupertino", "CA"]
```

and

```
["19369", "Stevens", "Creek", "Blvd,", "Cupertino", "CA"]
```

How would I go about doing this using `re.findall`?

Comment: `em.findall`. Do you mean `re.findall`?

Comment: Something like [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

Comment: For creating regexes, https://regex101.com/ is a really useful tool.

Comment: @SCB yes, I did my mistake